# What does optimize table do, or How do I rightfully optimize PK on the disk

Tags: mysql, optimization, primary-key, innodb

I was under the impression `OPTIMIZE TABLE` fixes fragmentation. So, if before I would do

```sql
select * from t -- (no order by, no nothing)
```

I would get the order of the records on the disk.
While after doing the optimize, and again running this query, the result would be ordered by the PK.
I just tried it on a table of mine, and nothing changed, I still get arbitrary order of records.

I am storing all my tables in one file. I am using InnoDB. MySQL 5.5
Am I missing something, should I have defined the PK somehow else?

Answer (score 1):

Without an `order by` statement you are never guaranteed order.

Your assumption of

> if before I would do select * from t (no order by, no nothing) I would
>   get the order of the records on the disk

is **wrong**.

How the Database decides to retrieve records and display them on the screen (or whatever you're viewing them through) is totally up to the internal implementation of the database. In the past this **might** have been disk order but the only way to know is to check if the Database (in your case MYSQL) mentions anything about it in their documentation.

I doubt they would though because then people would depend on this ordering and they couldn't improve their record retrieving algorithms without breaking things in the past.

### Edit:

As for optimizing the table try using an index that reflexes the query results you're looking for.

### Edit 2:

Another thought is that the situation you just described is a classic caching issue. Because the database already has the result set stored away somewhere in the original odd ordering, your optimization won't show a reordering until the cached data set is no longer cached. How you flush caches is a bit beyond my knowledge.